# Divide the gateway configuration yaml file into multiple files - Express Gateway

Tags: node.js, yaml, api-gateway, express-gateway

The gateway configuration file (yaml) for my Express gateway has grown to be quite large and has become unmanageable. It has all my apiEndpoints, policies and pipelines. I am trying to find a way to divide the file for it to be more manageable.